# Function return error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, promise

Code:

```
let parseCarList = [];

function addNewCars(req, res) {
    parseRequestAndCreateCarList(req.body)
        .then(function () {
            if (parseCarList.length != 0) {
                res.status(200).send('OK');
            }
        }, function (err) {
            res.status(200).send(err);
        });
}

function parseRequestAndCreateCarList(data) {
    return carListParsing(data);
}

function carListParsing(data, parentId = null) {
    //this function don't return anything
    //It parse req.body and fill the parseCarList array
    //I can't return anything because I use recursion
    parseCarList.push({
        car_company: data.car_company,
        parent_id: parentId
    });
    if (data.daughters) {
        data.daughters.forEach(item => {
            carListParsing(item, data.car_company);
        });
    }
}
```

My function carListParsing is to do array:

```
[ { car_company: 'vw', parent_id: null },
{ car_company: 'seat', parent_id: 'vw' }]
```

But I want to be sure, that it function will not block my code.

I get error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Is my function parseRequestAndCreateCarList return the promise that it has been fulfilled or not?
Why in this case the 'then' is undefined?

P.S. Is there a way to leave carListParsing without wrapper parseRequestAndCreateCarList?

Comment: "this function don't return anything. It parse req.body and fill the parseCarList array. I can't return anything because I use recursion" if it doesn't return anything, why are you expecting it to return a promise?

Comment: My thought exactly.  You're intentionally not returning anything, then wondering why you can't call a function on the non-existent result?

Comment: "*I can't return anything because I use recursion*" doesn't make any sense. Especially in the case of recursion, you always need to `return` something. Even when it's just the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @Cruiser I don't know how to use an asynchronous method with functions that don't return anything.

Comment: WTH are you trying to use promises? There's nothing asynchronous in your `parseRequestAndCreateCarList` and `carListParsing` functions!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I'm trying to understand exactly when asynchrony is used, and when not.

Answer (score -2):

You can only use **then** on a returned promise, so you need to change

```
function parseRequestAndCreateCarList(data) {
    return carListParsing(data);
}
```

to

```
function parseRequestAndCreateCarList(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(carListParsing(data))
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't. Either it's synchronous and doesn't need to use a promise, or it's asynchronous and already returns a promise. Also, this doesn't appear to be the problem in the OPs code.

Comment: If you really need to wrap some value in a promise, use `Promise.resolve(…)` instead of the promise constructor.